# Why do I get an "Unterminated quoted string" error?

Tags: makefile

This is my makefile for a particular C++ project, but when I run `make all`, I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:28: recipe for target '"system' failed
make: *** ["system] Error 2
```

When I change `exe` to something with no spaces, it works fine.

EDIT #1: The reason I used quotes was so I could use spaces in the output file name.

---

```
cc = g++

exe = "system software version 1.0"
src_dir = src
obj_dir = obj

src = $(wildcard $(src_dir)/*.cpp)
obj = $(patsubst $(src_dir)/%.cpp, $(obj_dir)/%.o, $(src))


libs = -lallegro -lallegro_primitives

include_paths = -I "include" -I "~/allegro5/include/"

lib_paths = -L "/usr/lib/"

flags = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g -std=c++14




all: $(exe)

play: all
    $(exe)

$(exe): $(obj)
    $(cc) $(lib_paths) $^ $(libs) -o $@

compile_only: $(obj)

$(obj_dir)/%.o: $(src_dir)/%.cpp
    $(cc) $(flags) $(include_paths) -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(obj_dir)/*.o

build: all

rebuild: clean build

.PHONY: all clean rebuild
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use paths containing whitespace with make.  There are crazy tricks that can make some limited things work, but basically it's simply not supported.

See this recent question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411000/939557